# Code Snippet VS AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a doubt with regards to Code Snippet VS AMPScript. To give bit of a context:

I have a campaign to run biweekly with a new discount code. Until now, every week i was going and manually making edits to every email content and more. I realised as i have all information of what the discounts are going to be in the future, i could create a code snippet and populate information via using flag in my query to get users the right content. And i used this code snippet by contentblockid in my ampscript and i marked the variables as **",@content_discount,"** but it was not populating the fields rightly.

<attached image - code_snippet_v1 + subject_line_v1 + amp_script_v1>
[image: amp_Script_v1] [image: code_snippet_v1][image: subject_line_v1][image: email_v1][image: email2_v1]

Set @subHeadlineTop   = concat("Get ",@content_discount," off")
Set @subHeadlineTop   = concat("Get", ",@content_discount,", "off")
But it did not work until. The same thing in subject line worked fine, but in the content part body/header it did not render.

Only when i used %%v=(@content_discount)=%% it populated the content.
Set @subHeadlineTop  = Concat("Get %%=v(@content_discount)=%%" , " off")

<attached image - code_snippet_v2 + amp_script_v2>
[![code_snippet_v2[image: subject_line_V2content_v2]

Could someone explain why?

The 2nd way i went about was defined attributes/variables and set all the content in the code snippet and pulled it to the email. And in the code snippet i used like this ",@content_discount," and it worked like magic.

Is there a difference of using these two that i am not aware off? I am a newbie to this, and any kind of clarity here would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the initial code (the first snippet in the screenshot) would've worked if the outer quote marks were changed from single to double. The `concat` for `@subHeadlineTop`...

```
concat('<br><b>Get ",@content_discount," off</b>')
```

...might look like three separate pieces are being joined together when skimming over the code, but if you notice the outer single quotes, the argument actually ends up being a single string. This is why you see the literal/unprocessed string `",@content_discount,"`. Compare this to the `concat` for `@subjectLine` which correctly uses matching quote marks.